# How can we disable iAds with a paid version?

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, adbannerview

I have created 2 target in my app. 1 for the free version, 1 for the paid version.

In my free version, I have an object ADBannerView in my view of my storyboard. But in my paid version I don't want ADBannerView in my storyboard. But I can't get rid of it.

I tried to hide my banner but [I have a rectangle of the object ADBannerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B31zn.png)

```
self.banner.hidden = YES;
self.banner = nil;
```

How can I do this ? By creating a second storyboard without ADBannerView ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you have just 1 app - the free version with ads? Then you can have an in-app purchase option to remove ads

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that !

Comment: I use two targets for a free and paid version of one of my apps.  As well as setting the banner to hidden you need to manipulate the constraints for your view so that the banner view is off-screen.  You will need this code anyway to ensure that the banner view is hidden when ads aren't being shown